# How to checkout the newest commit (tip of a branch)

Tags: git, github, git-checkout

Say I am on the tip of the Git graph and I am on the "latest" commit, let's call it commit-x. Say I checkout an older git commit with with

```
git checkout <commit-old>
```

After doing that, is there a way to checkout the latest commit again (commit-x), without having to know what commit-x is?

In other words, how can I checkout the tip of a Git branch automatically?

Comment: You can return to whatever you had previously checked out with `git checkout -`. When you check out a commit, though, you’re no longer on a branch, so you would have to specify the branch name again to get back to it (`git checkout master`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git checkout branch-name` is exactly what this does.

Answer (score 0):

```
git checkout branch-name # if you remember it
git checkout -           # if not & was the last checkout (may not have been)
<CTRL-KR> checkout       # To search shell history of checkout commands for last non-hash branch name
```